# data flow from child to parent in react

Tags: reactjs, components

I´m setting a timer, I´m trying to make the child component "Timer" to communicate to the parent component "App" so that the parent can change the Timers (one is for exercise time and the other for rest time); but is not working, the app starts but does not change the Timers. 
I´m new to coding and to StackOverflow so I would appreciate any directions and advice that anyone has on this matter.

I´m trying to use the `useEffect` hook to set the state "change" to "true" when the timer hits the "0" value. and then I want to call a function when "change" is "true" that calls the function above from the parent "App" that needs to change the state from "ExerciseTime" to "!ExerciseTime". obviously not working so far...

This is the parent component (I reduce it to only the part that has the actual problem):

```
function App() {
  const [exerciseTime, setExerciseTime] = useState(true);

  const handleTimer = () => {
    setExerciseTime(!exerciseTime);
  };


  return (
      </div>
      {exerciseTime ? <Timer time={5} change ={handleTimer()} /> : <Timer 
 time={3} change ={handleTimer} />}
       <div>
   );
 }
```

and this is the child component:

```
const Timer = props => {
 const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(props.time);
 const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
 const [change, setChange] = useState(false);

const toggle = () => {
  setIsActive(!isActive);
};

if (change) {
  props.change();
}

useEffect(() => {
 let interval = null;
  function changing() {
   setChange(!change);
 }

if (isActive && seconds !== 0) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1);
   }, 1000);
} else if (!isActive && seconds !== 0) {
   clearInterval(interval);
} else if (seconds === 0) {
   changing();
   clearInterval(interval)
}
return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [isActive, seconds, change]);

return (
  <div className="timer">
    <div className="timer-seconds">{seconds}</div>
    <div className="config-button">
      <button
        className={`button button-${isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
        onClick={toggle}
      >
        {isActive ? "Pause" : "Start"}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
};
```

I expect the Timer to change when arrives to "0" value, to the new Timer, and so on...

Comment: Both components (App and Timer) are using state. Would it make sense to push all the state to App, then push that down to a dumb component (Timer)? Timer would then be just a presentational component. Currently, I think this is a bit confusing.

Comment: I will try that; what I wanted is that the Timer component would be reusable, and the App controller would just manage when to change from one Timer to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You need to use the reference - `handleTimer` instead of calling the function `handleTimer()`.

Second: The way you're doing it, you're starting too many intervals. This will break your application.

Third: Even when the time prop changes, the Timer component is not unmounted, so the value will be 0 instead of 3 or 5, once the timer ends.

There are better ways you can do this, but I didn't want to go away from what you are doing, so modified it to make it work.

```
const Timer = props => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = React.useState(props.time);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      let interval;
      if (isActive && seconds !== 0) {
        interval = setInterval(
          () => setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1), 1000
        );
      }
      if (isActive && seconds === 0) {
        setIsActive(false)
        props.change()
      }
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }

    }, [isActive, seconds]);

  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <div className="timer-seconds">{seconds}</div>
      <div className="config-button">
        <button
          className={`button button-${isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
          onClick={toggle}
        >
          {isActive ? "Pause" : "Start"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [exerciseTime, setExerciseTime] = React.useState(true);

  const handleTimer = () => {
    setExerciseTime((exTime) => !exTime);
  };

  return (
    <div key={exerciseTime}>
      {exerciseTime ? <Timer time={5} change={handleTimer} /> : <Timer
        time={3} change={handleTimer} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Edit:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-lumiere-d7df7

Comment: Thanks!!! still doesn´t change from one timer to the other, it reaches to "0" and the button changes to start, but stays at "0" value, so it´s not mounting the new Timer?
Super helpfull your comment, I´m going to check the useEffect hook so that I understand it better. 
if you have some pointers as what to use to improve this, please do tell! Denins  told me in the comments above to use state in one component and communicate from parent to child only; is that it?

Comment: That's weird because it worked for me. Let me add it to codesandbox

Comment: Added the sandbox link. Check it out.

Comment: You are right! So it's something else in my code that is not allowing to re-render the timer; i'll have to check that... thank you!!!!

Comment: Should be this part:

interval = setInterval(
          () => setSeconds(seconds => seconds - 1), 1000
        );

There's no need to use the 'change' variable. Also adding the 'key' prop to the div in App component ensures that it re-renders the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the function, not the return value of the function to your change handler:

```
{exerciseTime ? <Timer time={5} change ={handleTimer} /> : <Timer time={3} change ={handleTimer} />}
```

Essentially `handleTimer()` should become `handleTimer`.

Comment: tried that just now, didn´t work =(; when Timer hits 0 seconds it stays there. You ar right still but it´s not the only thing wrong with my code..

Comment: `console.log()` at the top of `handleTimer()`. Is it being called?